# Event listener does not register click event on certain types of elements

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I'm making a Firefox extension to record user clicks on a website. I'm using eventListener to detect clicks on any elements on the website but for some reason clicks on input elements or dropdown options are not registered. Any idea on why this is? Here's the code for the extension:

```
alertClick : function(aEvent) {
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    window.alert("click");
}, false);
```

Comment: That code is not complete.. post the entire code or explain what getXPath is.. why is the listener added inside of it??

Comment: I have a button on my extension that starts the function getXPath. Right now all that it does is showing the alert "click" when a click event occur, but eventually I want it to record the xpath of the element.

Comment: @user3842589 - Firstly, welcome to SO. Please edit your question to provide a full, minimal, functional example. I've added a handler for click messages on both document and document.body - each of them register clicks on `<input>`  elements and `<option>` elements contained within a `<select>` element. It's hard to suggest fixes to incomplete code - the error is often in the code deemed not relevant. Furthermore detailing whether this behaviour is observed _only_ in an extension or in FireFox in general would be of benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited the code to reflect the goal I'm trying to achieve now. The behavior is observed in Firefox generally I believe, especially with a dynamic textbox (i.e one that changes size when clicked on)

Comment: Try `window.addEventListener` and then instead of `click` try `mouseup` or `mousedown`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changing the event to mouseup solved the problem.

Comment: `click` would also work, but if you `mousedown` then move your mouse (like more than 3px) and/or you wait long time and then do `mouseup` then `click` doesnt fire, just the `mouseup` will.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to solution:

Instead of `click` try `mouseup` or `mousedown`. The reason is because `click` does not fire IF you `mousedown` then move your mouse too much and/or wait a long time and then do `mouseup`.